# Permission denied: 'CreateObject' - ImageResizer

Tags: imageresizer

I just tried to install imageresizing.net com object. I'm using the following code to create the object.

```
set c = CreateObject("ImageResizer.Configuration.Config")
c.BuildImage "images\red-eye-wikipedia.jpg","test-image.jpg","width=100"
```

ERROR

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'

Permission denied: 'CreateObject'

/resizer.asp, line 5
```

---

I gave the folder that I'm trying to run the code the same permissions that I do for other folders. I don't know where to give the proper permissions.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You must give the DLL folder Read+Execute permissions for Everyone (or each of the usernames involved in running w3wp and ASP). Recursively.

C:\Program Files\ImageResizingNet\v3\